# React - LocalStorage & State - button toggle rendering issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, local-storage, use-effect

I have been grappling with this issue for a while...

I am having difficulties in utilising current state to display a toggle button which both adds and removes an item to local storage. The code below adds and removes correctly, but doesn't render correctly.

State is mirroring that which is in storage, but (I believe) the async nature of state allows for the rendering of the buttons to only work one way. When an item is added the button will change from add (+) to remove (x), but not the other way. Previous state keeps the button rendered permanently as a cross.

Is this a fundamental misapprehension of the functioning of React - is this solution inimical to its architecture, or is there a small change that would allow for this functionality to be realised?

Apologies for not isolating the problem area of code, but that's a key issue - I don't know what it is that is scuppering my efforts.

[CodeSandBox to example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-example-ofngb)

EDIT: Surprisingly, the CodeSandBox example functions as I want it to, but hosted locally this issue remains. What could be causing this disparity in performance?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [item, setItem] = useState("");
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);

  const favsLS = localStorage.getItem("drinks");

// Loads localStorage into state
  useEffect(() => {
    if (favsLS && favsLS.length > 15) {
      setFavourites(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("drinks")).filter(n => n));
    }
  }, []);

// Adds/Removes item from state
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!JSON.stringify(favourites).includes(item.id)) {
      setFavourites(favourites => [...favourites, item]);
    } else {
      favourites.forEach((drink, index) => {
        let favs = favourites;
        if (item.id === drink.id) {
          favs.splice(index, 1);
          setFavourites(favs);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [item]);

// Commits state to localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("drinks", JSON.stringify(favourites));
  }, [favourites]);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

// AJAX call
  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let cocktail = input;
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${cocktail}`
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    setData(data.drinks);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div className='field'>
      <h3>Search</h3>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input placeholder={"Enter..."} value={input} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
      </form>
      <div className='cocktails'>
        {data ? data.map((item, i) => (
              <div key={item.idDrink} className='card'>
                <h3>{item.strDrink}</h3>
                <div>
                  <button
                    className='fav-btn'
                    onClick={() => {
                      setItem({
                        id: item.idDrink,
                        name: item.strDrink,
                        image: item.strDrinkThumb
                      });
                      setFavourites(
                        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("drinks")).filter(n => n));
                    }}>
                    {JSON.stringify(favourites).includes(item.idDrink) ? "x" : "+"}
                  </button>
                  <img
                    className='cocktailImg'
                    src={item.strDrinkThumb}
                    alt=''
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          : ""}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: *"CodeSandBox to example"*  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: *"Surprisingly, the CodeSandBox example functions as I want it to..."* Then you'll have to figure out what the difference between that environment and yours is. Doing a Stack Snippet *might* help you do that, but...

Comment: There is some thing missing. on click of button you call `setItem` which inturn triggers the `useEffect` which inturn updates favourites. But you  are also calling setFavourites in the onClick method too. Streamlining these updates would get right results hopefully.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you both for your responses. Panther, that was indeed the problem! You've saved me many hours, thank you :)  And TJ, I will format correctly in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panther found the problem - two calls to update the same state value. By removing the call to setFavourites in the render, and moving the filter (.filter(n => n)) to its according useEffect the bug was removed.